# Задание № 20 ЕГЭ — анализ содержания текста

Tags: смысл, егэ, анализ-текста

> (1) В маленькой тёмной клетке с толстыми железными прутьями уже с десяток лет жила пара волков. (2) Хотя у многих обитателей зоопарка были имена, волки почему-то так и остались безымянными.
>
> Какие из высказываний соответствуют содержанию текста? Укажите номера ответов.
>   1) В зоопарке паре волков не дали имён, хотя другие животные не оставались безымянными.
>   ...

Является ли ответ «1» верным?

По-моему, нет, так как «другие животные не оставались безымянными» указывает на то, что другие животные имели имена, тогда как в тексте сказано: «У **многих** обитателей зоопарка». (Больше про имена в тексте нет ни слова.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *В зоопарке паре волков не дали имён...*
   Эта фраза означает, что имена животным раздавались (присваивались) именно в зоопарке. А это не так: их могли назвать и работники предыдущего зоопарка, и бывшие хозяева, и ветеринары c центра передержки — имена могли кочевать вместе с обитателями. Неточность.
2. *...паре волков не дали имён...* В предложении не говорится, что волкам давали или пытались давать имена. Сказано только, что по какой-то причине они остались безымянными. Еще одна.
3. *...другие животные не оставались безымянными.* Во втором предложении сказано, что у многих обитателей зоопарка были имена.
   А по этой формулировке можно понять, что только волки были без имен, а все остальные — с именами.
   Правильно было бы написать: большинство или бОльшая часть животных.

Возможно, правильный ответ мог бы выглядеть так:
Пара волков в зоопарке за десять лет так и не обзавелась именами, хотя большинство животных не оставались безымянными.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но в пособии этот ответ — самый что ни на есть верный!

Comment: Конечно, если абстрагироваться от смысловых неточностей, то ответ можно признать условно правильным. Кто ж их _такие_ пишет?

Comment: Я так и поняла: только волки были без имён, остальные с именами.